# How to set IO limit on RBD image (ceph qos settings)

Tags: ceph, qos, librbd

From the ceph [doc](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rbd/rbd-config-ref/#qos-settings) :

> librbd supports limiting per image IO, controlled by the following settings.

Running the commands from the doc prints `unknown options qos ...`.

I haven't found anything on the web so far. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the correct command [here](https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/36191).
I'm posting it here hoping it helps someone in the future.

At the image level:
`rbd config image set <pool>/<image> rbd_qos_iops_limit <value>`

At the pool level:
`rbd config pool set <pool> rbd_qos_iops_limit <value>`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ceph nautilus or octopus? QOS on rbd images released in nautilus and above.